# Segmentation fault when calling virtual function in C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, entity-component-system

I am currently working on an ECS in C++ for my game engine. I have a base system struct that has two virtual functions `init()` and `update()` which are implemented in derived structs. I have an `addSystem()` and `removeSystem()` functions which use templates and I have an array of `System*` systems. If I try to call them  it gives me a segmentation fault.

System:

```
struct System{
public:
    uint32_t id;
    virtual void init(World* world){}
    virtual void update(World* world){}
};
```

addSystem():

```
template<typename T>
    void addSystem(){
        T* system = allocate<T>();
        system->id = getID();
        systems.append(system);
        #ifdef DEBUG
                LOG("ECS: System added successfully.");
        #endif // DEBUG
}
```

removeSystem():

```
template<typename T>
    void removeSystem(uint32_t id){
        unsigned int index;
        for(int i = 0; i < systems.size; i++){
            if (systems[i]->id == id){
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        systems.remove(index);
}
```

Call to virtual function from System*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < systems.size; i++){
    systems[i]->init(this); // Here is the segmentation fault.
}

for (int i = 0; i < systems.size; i++){
    systems[i]->update(this); // Here is the segmentation fault.
}
```

Please ask if more info is needed.

Edit:
`size` is equal to 1 in the for loop and systems[i] is a valid pointer. I also tested `p systems[i]->update` and it also has a valid address. The problem is while calling it.

Comment: Can you share the code which segfaults when you call them directly? This shouldn't be happening. The point of virtual functions is to not have to "remember" what type this ptr came from and let the VTABLE do the job

Comment: Have you tried using `valgrind` or gcc/clang's address sanitizer?  Either would provide a lot more information.

Comment: @StephenNewell I used the code blocks debugger and when I type `p system[i]->update(this)` it says `Cannot access memory at address 0x8`.

Comment: I can't investigate without a working example (which I can run). But you mostly need to address the segfault and not look for ways for conversion to original type. If you can provide a `minimal reproducible example` I might be able to help more. Also, I'm assuming systems is a standard container in which case you need to call size() not size

Comment: That error sounds like `system[i]` is `nullptr`.  How positive are you that `size` is right?

Comment: @JatinSharma Sorry I am also unable to reproduce it outside my game engine code.

Comment: @StephenNewell `systems[i]` is a valid address to `System*` according to the debugger.

Comment: Then I'll again suggest `valgrind`.

Comment: @JatinSharma `systems` is of custom size `List<typename>` which works with my own memory manager.

Comment: @StephenNewell It says the same thing `Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently)free'd`

Comment: Updated the question because it didn't work after casting as well.

Comment: I notice that that `System` doesn't have a virtual destructor.  If you're `delete`ing objects of classes derived from `System` via a `System*` that could cause mysterious problems like this.

Comment: @MilesBudnek It still gives segmentation fault.

Comment: 0x8 strongly suggests to me that you've got a null pointer, especially since a pointer on a 64-bit system is (probably) 8 bytes.  I'd add assertions in your loop to verify `system[i]` is valid.  Since you're using a non-standard data structure, you probably want to verify that `size` is updated appropriately.

Comment: There's also a potential bug in `removeSystem` in case the matching id is never found.  That's probably unrelated though.

Comment: Can you post the full backtrace of the error, as provided by Valgrind?

Comment: @Uninitialized Sorry, it is so long that it exceeds 30000 characters.

Comment: @StephenNewell The edit answers your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#ifndef SYSTEMTEST_H_
#define SYSTEMTEST_H_

#include <stdint.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct World
{
    int id;
};

struct System{
public:
    uint32_t id;
    virtual void init(World* world){}
    virtual void update(World* world){}
};

int systemID = 0;
std::vector<System*> systems;


struct Derived : System
{
    void init(World* world){
        std::cout << "init" << std::endl;
    }
    void update(World* world){
        std::cout << "update" << std::endl;
    }
};

uint32_t getID()
{
    return systemID++;
}

template<typename T> void addSystem(){
    T* system = new T();
    system->id = getID();
    //systems.append(system);
    systems.push_back(system);
}

template<typename T> void removeSystem(uint32_t id){
    unsigned int index;
    for (int i = 0; i < systems.size; i++){
        if (systems[i]->id == id){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    //remove operator
    //systems.remove(index);
}
#endif
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SystemTest.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    addSystem<Derived>();
    for (int i = 0; i < systems.size(); i++)
    {
        World *world;
        world = new World;
        systems[i]->init(world);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I understand your description.

I try to complete the rest

Run was successful

Comment: It works for me as well. But can you tell me what you did to make it work.

Comment: System cannot be instantiated because there are virtual functions. You must Inheriting System  and implementing methods.

Comment: I still don't understand, that's what I am doing.

Comment: what do you want to do ?